# Search / Filter a list works on chrome / firefox but not in safari (HTML & JavaScript) - JavaScript enabled on Safari

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, safari

I have the following code which works perfectly fine in any browser apart from safari, displaying a list of football clubs. Afterwards I have implemented a search bar, filtering the list with javascript.

Filtering works in chrome. Safari only displays the list of clubs and does nothing when typing in the filtering box. Everything has been tried on the settings side of safari and multiple computers have been used.

Maybe someone has an idea what is wrong...

```
<input type="text" id="filter" oninput="filterDropdown()" placeholder="Type to filter" >
                                
<select id="dropdown" name="club_name" class="form-select bg-custom" size="17" aria-label="Size 10 select example" style="background-color: #B9B4C7;" >
                                <!-- <option selected></option> -->
                                {% for name in df["name"] %}
                                <option class="list bg-custom" data-league="{{ df[df['name']==name]['league'].values[0] }}" value="{{ name }}" {% if loop.first %}selected{% endif %}>{{ name }}</option>
                                {% endfor %}
</select>
```

JavaScript

```
function filterDropdown() {
            // Get input value
            var input, filter, dropdown, options, i, txtValue;
            input = document.getElementById("filter");
            filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
            dropdown = document.getElementById("dropdown");
            options = dropdown.getElementsByTagName("option");

            // Loop through all options, hide those that don't match the filter
            for (i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
                txtValue = options[i].text;
                if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                    options[i].style.display = "";
                } else {
                    options[i].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do you mean javscript? You mean javascript. Definitely not the same thing. Also, I don't think you can style options object in `<select>` fields - Chrome allows it, but that's non-standard. You should remove them and add them back instead, or perhaps disabled them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all browsers handle styling of form fields the same way: [The HTML Select element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select#styling_with_css).

First I refactored your example. It doesn't solve the problem.

```js
document.forms.form01.filter.addEventListener('input', e => {
  let form = e.target.form;
  let filter = e.target.value.toUpperCase();
  [...form.club_name.options].forEach(option => {
    option.classList.add('hidden');
    if (option.text.toUpperCase().startsWith(filter)) {
      option.classList.remove('hidden');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
option.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form name="form01">
  <input type="text" name="filter" placeholder="Type to filter">
  <select id="dropdown" name="club_name" class="form-select bg-custom" size="5" aria-label="Size 10 select example" style="background-color: #B9B4C7;">
    <option class="list bg-custom" value="1">Abc</option>
    <option class="list bg-custom" value="2">Abcde</option>
    <option class="list bg-custom" value="3">Abcdefg</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

And then an example that might help where all options are removed and added to the DOM. All options are stored in a array and the function `refresh_options()` can be used for, first removing and then inserting options.

```js
const options = [{text:'Abc',value:1},{text:'Abcde',value:2},{text:'Abcdefg',value:2}];

refresh_options(document.forms.form01.club_name, options);

document.forms.form01.filter.addEventListener('input', e => {
  let form = e.target.form;
  let text = e.target.value.toUpperCase();
  let filteredoptions = options.filter(opt => opt.text.toUpperCase().startsWith(text));
  refresh_options(form.club_name, filteredoptions);
});

function refresh_options(select, filteredoptions){
  select.textContent = '';
  filteredoptions.forEach(opt => {
     let optelm = document.createElement("option");
     optelm.value = opt.value;
     optelm.text = opt.text;
     select.add(optelm);
  });
}
```

```html
<form name="form01">
  <input type="text" name="filter" placeholder="Type to filter">
  <select id="dropdown" name="club_name" class="form-select bg-custom" size="5" aria-label="Size 10 select example" style="background-color: #B9B4C7;">
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: thanks, that looks great and sorry for the late response. I had a few rough days.
It seems like the table gets populated by the const options in the javascript. How would I manage to pass a table from my flask app to the javascript variable...
Probably a newbish question, but I am trying to learn

Comment: Something like: `const options = {% for name in df["name"] %}
{"name": "{{ name }}", "value": "something"},
{% endfor %}];`
in a stript tage somewhere. Just like you create the option elements in your HTML.

Comment: you are my personal jesus for today. Thanks